# Proving that $F(x)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{p-1}\left(\frac{k}{p}\right)x^k$ has at least $\frac{p-1}{2}$ different complex roots

Tags: number-theory, polynomials

> Let $p$ be odd prime number. Show that
> $$F(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}\left(\frac{k}{p}\right)x^k$$
> has at least $\dfrac{p-1}{2}$ different complex roots $z$ with $|z|=1$,
> where $\left(\dfrac{k}{p}\right)$ is Legendre's symbol.

I try: since $F(1)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{p-1}\left(\dfrac{k}{p}\right)=0$,so $1$ is a one complex root in $M:=\{z\mid z\in \mathbb C,\ |z|=1\}$. If $p\equiv 1\pmod 4$, then we have
$$F'(1)=\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}k\left(\frac{k}{p}\right)=\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}(p-k)\left(\frac{p-k}{p}\right)\\
=(-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}(p-k)\left(\frac{k}{p}\right)=-(-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}F'(1).$$
Since $p\equiv 1\pmod 4$, so we have $F'(1)=0$. But I can't continue solving this problem.

Comment: Look at the article referenced [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fekete_polynomial).

Comment: Here some thoughts. Denote $\omega:=e^{\frac{2\pi i}{p}}=\cos\frac{2\pi}{p}+i\sin{\frac{2\pi}{p}}$ (primitive $p$-th root of unity). Now, consider values of $f(x)$ at points $1,\omega,\ldots,\omega^{p-1}$. It's easy to check that (using properties of the Legendre's symbol)
$$
f(\omega^k)=\left(\frac{k}{p}\right)\cdot f(\omega)~\text{for}~k\in\{0,1,2,\ldots,p-1\}.
$$
Hence, among numbers $f(\omega^k)$, $k\in\{0,1,\ldots,p-1\}$ there $\frac{p-1}{2}$ numbers which are equal to $c:=f(\omega)$, $\frac{p-1}{2}$ numbers which are equal to $-c$ and zero ($f(1)=0$).

Comment: Further, you need to find some realvalued finction related with $F$ and use the intermediate value theorem and Gauss lemma, that's described in upper link.

Comment: It's getting harder and harder to decipher such pseudo-English but I made my best to edit this post.

Comment: Just a few observations $$F(x)=x\cdot\left(1+\sum\limits_{k=2}^{p-2}\left(\frac{k+1}{p}\right)x^k\right)=x\cdot G(x)$$
Because $G\in\mathbb{R}[x]$ [then](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_conjugate_root_theorem), if $G(z)=0 \Rightarrow G(\overline{z})=0$. Also, by [Vieta's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas), $1=\left|\prod\limits_{G(z)=0}z\right|$. So, you need to find at least $\frac{p-1}{4}$ different complex roots $|z|=1$.

Comment: I corrected an obvious mistake

Comment: Allow $p$ to be non-prime. For what $p$ is the number of roots on the unit circle the maximum value of $p-1$?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$$F(e^{i t})= \sum_{k=1}^{p-1} \left(\frac{k}p\right) e^{ikt}=
\sum_{k=1}^{p-1} \left(\frac{p-k}p\right) e^{i(p-k)t}\\=
e^{ipt}\left(\frac{-1}p\right)\sum_{k=1}^{p-1} \left(\frac{k}p\right) e^{-ikt}=
e^{ipt}i^{p-1} \overline{F(e^{it})}
 $$
So $e^{-ipt/2}i^{-(p-1)/2} F(e^{it})$ is real valued.

For $p\nmid a$ with $ab\equiv 1\bmod p$
$$F(e^{2i\pi a/p}) =
\sum_{k=0}^{p-1} \left(\frac{k}p\right) e^{2i\pi ak/p}=
\sum_{k=0}^{p-1} \left(\frac{bk}p\right) e^{2i\pi 
abk/p}\\=\left(\frac{b}p\right) F(e^{2i\pi /p})= \left(\frac{a}p\right)F(e^{2i\pi/p}) $$

Next $$\sum_{k=0}^{p-1} \left(\frac{k}p\right)\left(\frac{k+1}p\right)=
\left(\frac{a^2}p\right)\sum_{k=0}^{p-1} \left(\frac{bk}p\right)\left(\frac{bk+1}p\right)$$ $$=
\sum_{k=0}^{p-1} \left(\frac{abk}p\right)\left(\frac{abk+a}p\right)=
\sum_{k=0}^{p-1} \left(\frac{k}p\right)\left(\frac{k+a}p\right)$$
so that
$$\sum_{k=0}^{p-1} \left(\frac{k}p\right)\left(\frac{k+1}p\right)=\sum_{k=0}^{p-1} \left(\frac{k}p\right)\frac1{p-1}\sum_{a=1}^{p-1}\left(\frac{k+a}p\right)= 
\sum_{k=1}^{p-1} \left(\frac{k}p\right)\frac{-1}{p-1}\left(\frac{k}p\right) = -1 $$

This implies that there are $\frac{p-1}{2}$ values of $k\in 1\ldots p-2$ such that $\left(\frac{k}p\right)\left(\frac{k+1}p\right)=-1$

> For the other $\frac{p-3}{2}$ values it will be $\left(\frac{k}p\right)\left(\frac{k+1}p\right)=1$. For each of those $k$ we'll get that $e^{-ipt/2}i^{-(p-1)/2} F(e^{it})$ changes of sign on $t\in (\frac{2\pi k}p,\frac{2\pi (k+1)}p)$.

Whence we get at least $\frac{p-3}{2}$ zeros of $F(e^{it})$ on $[\frac{2\pi}p,2\pi-\frac{2\pi}p]$. Together with $F(1)=0$ it gives at least $\frac{p-1}{2}$ distinct zeros of $F(x)$ on the unit circle.

Comment: You really know your stuff. I think you have an x as a typo in the initial formulas when you evaluate F along those discrete set of points ?

Comment: How did you have the idea to consider the sum over k of (k/p)((k+1)/p) ? Is it a standard result or you had the idea just to solve this problem?

Comment: Both. I saw that the problem could follow from looking at it, and it is a Jacobi sum so I knew it was computable. Can't see the typo.

Comment: Inside the summation you have $e^{2i\pi akx/p}$, what is x there?

Comment: Thanks for sharing the thought process :)

Answer (score -1):

Definition of Legendre Symbol : [Legendre_symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_symbol).

For p prime the Legendre Symbol equals the Jacobi Symbol. Or the Legendre Symbol is the Jacobi Symbol restricted to primes. Theses are only $+1$ or $-1$ values.

For p=1 this is trivially true: no zeros.

For p=2 this is $x$ and has only one zero confirming the formula.

For p=3 this is $x-x^2$ and confirms again the formula $\frac{3-1}{2}=1$. Oh no. This contradicts already the formula. I $three$ not prime? Okay, $3$ is not an odd prime number. No. $3$ is an odd prime number! So this is a contradiction.

For p=5: $x+x^2-x^3+x^4$ We have $x(1+x-x^2+x^3)=(-1 + x)^2 x (1 + x)$ gives $\frac{5-1}{2}=\frac{4}{2}=2$ zeros. No! This are $\{0,-1,1\}$ with this multiplicity of $2$ for $1$. Okay this are three root and the formular is for least roots so three different roots match the least roots count.

I think your formula is not well-posed.

A table for experimenting:

$
 {5, (-1 + x)^2 x (1 + x)}$,
${7, -(-1 + x) x (1 + 2 x + x^2 + 2 x^3 + x^4)}$,
${11, -(-1 + x) x (1 + x^2 + 2 x^3 + 3 x^4 + 2 x^5 + x^6 + x^8)}$,
$ {13, (-1 + x)^2 x (1 + x) (1 + 2 x^2 + 2 x^3 + 3 x^4 + 2 x^5 + 
     2 x^6 + x^8)}$,
${17, (-1 + x)^2 x (1 + x) (1 + 2 x + 2 x^2 + 4 x^3 + 3 x^4 + 4 x^5 + 
     2 x^6 + 4 x^7 + 3 x^8 + 4 x^9 + 2 x^10 + 2 x^11 + x^12)}$,
${19, -(-1 + x) x (1 - x^2 + x^4 + 2 x^5 + 3 x^6 + 2 x^7 + 3 x^8 + 
     2 x^9 + 3 x^{10} + 2 x^{11} + x^{12} - x^{14} + x^{16})}$,
${23, -(-1 + x) x (1 + 2 x + 3 x^2 + 4 x^3 + 3 x^4 + 4 x^5 + 3 x^6 + 
     4 x^7 + 5 x^8 + 4 x^9 + 3 x^{10} + 4 x^{11} + 5 x^{12} + 4 x^{13} + 
     3 x^{14} + 4 x^{15} + 3 x^{16} + 4 x^{17} + 3 x^{18} + 2 x^{19} + x^{20})}$,
${29, (-1 + x)^2 x (1 + x) (1 + x^4 + 2 x^5 + 4 x^6 + 4 x^7 + 7 x^8 + 
     6 x^9 + 8 x^{10} + 6 x^{11} + 9 x^{12} + 6 x^{13} + 8 x^{14} + 6 x^{15} + 
     7 x^{16} + 4 x^{17} + 4 x^{18} + 2 x^{19} + x^{20} + x^{24})}$

How did I compute my polynomials?
I did use the definitions from my reference page [Legendre_symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_symbol) and used the given formula.
I selected only odd primes. For reference see [odd primes](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/OddPrime.html#:%7E:text=Any%20prime%20number%20other%20than,therefore%20the%20%22oddest%22%20prime.&text=The%20Penguin%20Dictionary%20of%20Curious%20and%20Interesting%20Numbers.). I factored in the polynomial making them look somewhat strange.

So here with counting:

[image: number of different roots of F(x) over Reals for the further odd primes]

Seems the given formula is wrong over reals.

Over complexes, the number of zeros follows the simple degree formula.

[image: number of different roots of F(x) over Complexes for the further odd primes]

So what. $p-1$ is the number of roots over the complexes. This follows from the fact that the degree of the polynomial $F(x)$ is that high and the roots will be different for each odd primes $p$ guaranteed by the used [Legendre_symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_symbol).

For the induction step, it suffices that the [Legendre_symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_symbol) of the next odd prime p of the highest degree in the polynomial is non-zero. The next higher degree occurs in the polynomial and therefore the next new zero occurs.

That is all that has to be proven.